# is there some constant $C\in{\mathbb{R}}$ for every Borel subset of $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite measures s.t $\nu<<\mu$. Is it true or false that there exists a constant $C$ for every $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ s.t. $\nu(A)\leq{C\mu(A)}$.

my intuition tells me no, but I can't think of counter example.

Comment: Surely you actually meant to ask whether there exists $C$ such that for every $A$[etc]? The way you phrased the question, $C$ is allowed to depend on $A$; surely that's not what you intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Define
$$\mu = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} 3^{-n}\chi_{\{\frac1n\}}$$ 
and
$$\nu = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} 2^{-n}\chi_{\{\frac1n\}}$$
We have $\nu<<\mu$ and both are finite measures but 
$$\frac{\nu(\{\frac1n\})}{\mu(\{\frac1n\})} = (\frac32)^n \rightarrow \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much easier to think of a counter-example on $[0,\infty)$ (by applying a suitable map and a push-forward, this is equivalent to finding a counter example on $[0,1)$).

Now, let $\mu(A)=\int_A e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\textrm{d}x$ and $\nu(A)= \int_A e^{-x}\textrm{d}x.$ Then, both measures are equivalent to the Lesbegue measure and hence, $\nu<<\mu$. However, if $A_n=[n,n+1]$ we see that

$$
\mu(A_n)\leq e^{-\frac{n^2}{2}} \\
 \nu(A_n)\geq e^{-(n+1)}
$$
and so, we see that
$$
\frac{\nu(A_n)}{\mu(A_n)}\to \infty
$$
as $n\to \infty$, so no, we cannot find such a constant.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $\mu$ the uniform probability on $[0,1]$ and $\nu(A)=\int_{A\cap (0,1]} \lvert x\rvert^{-1/2}\,dx$. Then $\frac{\nu(0,x)}{\mu(0,x)}=2x^{-1/2}$, which diverges as $x\to 0^+$.